# How to use jquery to change css depending on a condition on dates?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my web page, I have a table of dates (my date format is dd-mm-yyyy)

```
<tr>
    <td>05-03-2012</td>
    <td name="expiration">09-07-2012</td>
    <td>08-10-2012</td>
 <tr>
```

What I want is to put in red color expiration dates when their value is > current date, using Jquery.

So, I think I am going to use something like :

```
<script>
//don't know how to retrieve the expiration date and check if it is after the
//current date 

$('td[name=expiration]').css({"color":"red"});
</script>
```

Comment: I can help you with this, but I need to know if your date formate will always be mm-dd-yyyy

Comment: Ok thanks! My date format will always be dd-mm-yyyy actually as I am using Twig using {{ object.dateExpiration | date (d-m-Y) }} to display this date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prefer to use a class instead of a name so your selector is more efficient:

```
<tr>
    <td>05-03-2012</td>
    <td class="expiration-date">09-07-2012</td>
    <td>08-10-2012</td>
</tr>

var now = new Date;
$('.expiration-date').text(function (i, v) {
    if (now < new Date(v)) {
        $(this).addClass('unexpired');
    }
});
```

Here's an example in a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qRdNe/

Comment: console.log( new Date(v) );  returns invalid date, does this code really work

Comment: It works just fine, as demonstrated by this modified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qRdNe/6/

Comment: There is a problem with the date format, when I add var date = new Date(v); alert(date); I have an alert "Invalid date". (My format is dd-mm-yyy).

Comment: OK so I had to parse the date using var str = v.split("-"); var date = new Date(str[2],str[1]-1,str[0],0,0,0,0); I don't know why but if I kept str[1] it will add a month . Thanks your help!

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't account for any errors in date time parsing.

```
$('td[name=expiration]').each(function(){

    var innerText = $(this).text();
    var date = new Date(innerText);
    var today = new Date();    

    if(date > today){
       //Set css here
    }
    else{
       //Set default here
    }

});
```

Comment: to handle date parsing, use this answer, but add the following lines (above the first line of the function, and change the `Date` object construction for the variable `date` as described below:



    `var str = innerText.split("-");`


    `var date = new Date(str[2],str[0],str[1],0,0,0,0);`

Comment: There is no need to go to such lengths to parse the Date string. The Date object will do it just fine for you: http://jsfiddle.net/qRdNe/6/

Comment: there are some strings the Date object can handle if passed directly, this is not one of them.  If you try to initiate the `Date` object with the text of once of these cells, you'll get the wrong date.  Using the string from her example, you get Dec 31, 1969.

Answer (score 0):

I have basically put together a working answer its from different bits given here but corrected where needed, the date for a month starts from zero. Maybe you don't want to accept this as the right answer , i'm just putting all of it here so its easy to reference.

```
$('.expiration').text(function(i,v){
    var datestr = v.split("-");
    d = new Date(datestr[2],datestr[0]-1,datestr[1],0,0,0,0);
    var now = new Date();        
    if(console)console.log(d);        
    if(d>now )
             {
                $(this).css("color","red");            
             }                

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6zb5W/3/

Comment: This fiddle is the same version number as mine

Comment: In FF 12 im using it gives an invalid date, even if the date is before now it still highlights the date

Comment: Looks to be a FF specific issue. The date parses fine in Chrome and IE9, but FF 13 does not handle the date correctly